# VPL start with java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt

I am trying to create a generic node that can modified and to ones wishes but I have run in some trouble because my skills in Swing and such is not so good.

Problem 1: I can't seem to get two Node/Jpanels in the same JFrame.

lesser Problem 2: The stroke is cut off from the JPanel border (Should I build in a kind of bleed so this will not happen?)

Any aid is helpful :)

```
public class SimpleGui {

    public SimpleGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        NodePanel panel = new NodePanel(3, 2);
        panel.setLayout(new javax.swing.SpringLayout());
        frame.add(panel);

        NodePanel panel2 = new NodePanel(3, 2);
        panel2.setLayout(new javax.swing.SpringLayout());
        frame.add(panel2);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        panel.setLocation(50, 50);
        panel2.setLocation(150, 150);
    }
}
```

The generic node/panel class that is added to the JFrame:

```
public class NodePanel extends JPanel {

    private int x = 0, int y = 0;    
    private PortPanel inPortPanel;
    private PortPanel outPortPanel;    
    int iH;
    int oH;    
    private int width = 120;
    private int height = 30;    
    Graphics2D g2;

    public NodePanel(int input, int output) {

        inPortPanel = new PortPanel(input);
        this.add(inPortPanel);

        outPortPanel = new PortPanel(output);
        this.add(outPortPanel);

        setPreferredSize(calculateDimension());
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));

        inPortPanel.setLocation(x, y + (height - iH) / 2);
        outPortPanel.setLocation(x + width, y + (height - oH) / 2);

        drawNode();
    }

    private void drawNode() {
        g2.drawRoundRect(x, y, width, height, 5, 5);
    }

    private Dimension calculateDimension() {

        iH = inPortPanel.getPreferredSize().height;
        int iW = inPortPanel.getPreferredSize().width;
        oH = outPortPanel.getPreferredSize().height;
        height = iH > oH ? iH + iW : oH + iW;

        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

The port panel that is part of the Node Panel

```
public class PortPanel extends JPanel {

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int portWidth = 14;
    int portHeight = 14;
    int count = 0;
    int offset = 22;
    Graphics2D g2;

    public PortPanel(int i) {
        this.count = i;
        setPreferredSize(calculateDimensions());        
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        drawPorts();
    }

    private void drawPorts() {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            g2.fillOval(x, y + (i * offset), portWidth, portHeight);
        }
    }

    private Dimension calculateDimensions(){
        int overallHeight = (offset * (count-1)) + portHeight;
        return new Dimension(portWidth,overallHeight);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Node should be a logical class, not a GUI component class.
- You should have a single drawing JPanel that can draw all the visual representation of your logical entities.
- This way the model can hold multiple logical entities that all can be drawn by the single drawing JPanel without having to worry as much about layout managers.
- Don't forget to call your JPanel's `super.paintComponent` method within its override method so your JPanel can do house-keeping painting.
- Avoid giving your JPanels Graphics or Graphics2D fields as that increases the risk of your code throwing a NPE. Use the Graphics object given to your paintComponent method, and if you need to use it in another method that is called by paintComponent, **pass** it into that method.

Comment: Could you elaborate on super.paintComponent? Rest is understood.

Comment: @Josephus87: If you don't call the super's method, the JPanel can't do housekeeping painting including painting over dirty pixels.

Comment: @Josephus87 Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for details about how painting works in Swing

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels So if I e.g. double click on my all doing JPanel… it creates a Node and draws it… but how am I passing in the Graphics object in for starters?

Comment: Ah forgettaboutit I just learned that JavaFX is a lot simpler handling layouts and styles. All Swing books should be burned for being so old fashioned.